# Getting a 'x0' is infeasible error when trying to curve fit with bounds

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to do a multi-gaussian deconstruction of a spectral measurement I took, but I'm getting `ValueError: 'x0' is infeasible`. I'm using `curve_fit` and I'm trying to break down my measurement into 3 Gaussians. Here's my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

```
directory=r"C:\Users\jh\data"
filename = "test(0,1).txt"
filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, delimiter = "\t")

x = data['Wavelength (nm)']
y = data['Absorbance']
```

```
#Gaussian 1
amp1 = 100
cen1 = 450
sig1 = 15

#Gaussian 2
amp2 = 50
cen2 = 550
sig2 = 10

#Gaussian 3
amp3 = 20
cen3 = 760
sig3 = 5

p0 = [amp1, cen1, sig1, amp2, cen2, sig2, amp3, cen3, sig3]
```

```
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, sig):
    gau = amp*(1/(sig*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1/2)*(((x-cen)/sig)**2)))
    return gau

def three_gaussian(x, amp1, cen1, sig1, amp2, cen2, sig2, amp3, cen3, sig3): #Amp: Amplitude, Cen: Center, Sig: Sigma
    gau1 = amp1*(1/(sig1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1/2)*(((x-cen1)/sig1)**2)))
    gau2 = amp2*(1/(sig2*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1/2)*(((x-cen2)/sig2)**2)))
    gau3 = amp3*(1/(sig3*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1/2)*(((x-cen3)/sig3)**2)))
    return gau1 + gau2 + gau3
```

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(three_gaussian, x, y, p0, bounds = ((400, -np.inf, -np.inf, 500, -np.inf, -np.inf, 650, -np.inf, -np.inf), (470, np.inf, np.inf, 600,  np.inf, np.inf, 900,  np.inf, np.inf)))

RRa_pars = popt[0:3]
RRe_pars = popt[3:6]
Pol_pars = popt[6:9]

RRa = gaussian(x, *RRa_pars)
RRe = gaussian(x, *RRe_pars)
Pol = gaussian(x, *Pol_pars)
```

I'm positive that the problem is this line from the `curve_fit` call:

```
popt = curve_fit(three_gaussian, x, y, p0, bounds = ((400, -np.inf, -np.inf, 500, -np.inf, -np.inf, 650, -np.inf, -np.inf), (470, np.inf, np.inf, 600,  np.inf, np.inf, 900,  np.inf, np.inf)))
```

I previously tried this code without the bounds and it was working, but the model was inaccurate to what I was expecting. So I introduced the bounds to try and constrain the center to where I was expecting. That's what introduced the `ValueError: 'x0' is infeasible`. This is what the fit looks like without the bounds:

[image]

The fit is good, but the two Gaussians should be closer in amplitude and they should be more shifted left. (I'm neglecting the last Gaussian in this image because it's not the one with a problem).

I'm not really sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: At a quick glance, your bounds for `amp1` are 400 and 470, but your initial guess is 100, which is outside the bounds (making the initial guess infeasible since it doesn't satisfy your bounds).

Comment: Oh my god, that was exactly the problem. I meant to bound the cen values, not the amp values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide bounds and an initial guess, the initial guess must satisfy the bounds, otherwise the initial guess is considered "infeasible" (that's just another way of saying it doesn't satisfy the constraints). Consider this modified version of the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` example from the documentation.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
y_noise = 0.2*rng.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5) + y_noise
```

If we call the curve fit like so:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=(2., 0.6, 0.2), bounds=(0, [3., 2., 1.]))
```

There aren't any issues because the initial guess satisfies the constrains.

But if we call it like this:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=(4., 0.6, 0.2), bounds=(0, [3., 2., 1.]))
```

We get `ValueError: 'x0' is infeasible` since the `a` initial guess is not within the bounds.